# XHttpRequest 2 page progress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on reading some documents from mozilla i just wanted to try out the html5 "xhr2" (so called) functionality. SO i used this code...

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();


function transferComplete(evt) {
  alert("The transfer is complete.");
}   

oReq.upload.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);        
oReq.open('POST',"https://www.google.com",true);
```

I placed the above code in the head section of my page , but the page always loads but none of the events are fired..

Could someone please tell me what im doing wrong ....

Thanks guys

Comment: remove **upload** before addEventLIstener

Comment: thanks roman :D... but still no dice mate...... nothin happening at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's couple problems in your code.

1. you need to remove keyword **upload** before addEventLIstener
2. you need to call **send()** method on oReq object
3. [cross-origin policy](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) won't allow you to load https://www.google.com, but you still can load documents on the same domain

check this code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

function transferComplete(evt) {
  alert("The transfer is complete.");
}   

oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);   
oReq.open('GET',"/index.html", true);
oReq.send();
```

[try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ye9y5z/2/)

Comment: thanks .... noted bout cross domain, but the thing on same domain... aint happening mate..... im testing this out of localhost...i have a big list of images on a page..... trying to load that but no dice.

Comment: Can u gimme and example for say a page (url) like this http://localhost/foldername/script

Comment: Yep i did roman, thanks for that. but i got it to work for the image beautifully thanks to you. But im kinda getting flustered with the html pages lol

Comment: i updated sample, now it loads html file, it still works on JSFiddle

Comment: ok i see that you have altered your code, but does this work for a FQDN like http://mywebsite.com/somewhere, where the script is run on mywebsite itself, or is it still considered cross domain.

Comment: But i assume, the total size of the page is unknown and so the total progress cannot be loaded rite ?

Comment: That's another question, try to search, i found some posts [here](/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)